# Bundling and Minifying Durandal Applications

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal, durandal-2.0

I'm using MVC5/Durandal and wondering what the recommended approach to bundling/minifying a durandal application would be.  Ive seen docs on using Weyland but will be deploying to an Azure Website and don't see how to leverage this in my .net-based deployment process.  How can I go about configuring automated bundling/minification of my durandal application when deploying to Azure?

Answer (score 4):

I've spent a bit of time trying to optimize an AngularJS application for one of the biggest banks in Holland. Although it's no Durandal, this might still give you some ideas.

So what did we use for bundling and minification? Out-of-the-box bundling and minifcation from ASP.NET MVC ( which is from the `system.web.optimization` namespace )

You need to get a couple of things in order to leverage this:

**Organize your files**

Organize your code files in a way that they can easily be bundled. We had a large tree structure under the `/app` folder in the web project. Something like:

```
- App      
   |- Modules
   |     |-Common
   |     |    |- Directives
   |     |    |- Templates
   |     |    |- Filters
   |     --User
   |          ...
   | app.js
```

So the application skeleton was inside the `app.js` and all the other JS files were required by the application. Point being: all SPA code is separated from vendor javscript files and the rest of course

**Set up the budling inside the bundle configuration**

That's a breeze now, just do regular-old-bundling from your `Global.asax.cs`:
Make sure there's a line in the `Application_Start()` with:
`BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

That calls into your `BundleConfig` class which only needs 1 bundle to pack up the whole `/app` folder:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app")
            .Include("~/app/*.js")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true));
```

We needed the `app.js` to load first - therefore we put it explicitly at the top. Don't worry, it will not be requested twice.

For bundling - only the sequence of files can be important. However, through including that file explicitly, we could control that and it worked like a charm.

**Minification**

Now for minification we had to do some code changes. AngularJS can be used with different types of syntax - some of which can be minified, others give problems.

Example:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller(function($http,$scope) { ... });
```

can not be minified. The minifyer will change the name of `$http` so something shorter, after which the injector cannot do dependency injection anymore, since it only knows stuff called `$http` and `$scope` and not the minified variable name.

So for Angular you need to use a different syntax:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller(['$http', '$scope', function($http,$scope) { ... }]);
```

With this, the injector will know that the first argument of the function is '$http' because that's the first string variable in the array. OK, but that's Angular and you're looking for Durandal.

I've heard that Durandal uses AMD right? So within a module, minification shouldn't be a problem, because it should be smart enough. However, if you're using external things, you want to make sure everything still works. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585774/bundling-and-minifying-modular-javascript-requirejs-amd-with-asp-net-mvc) that you'll want to use te following syntax for your AMDs:

```
define("someModule", ["jquery", "ko"], function($,ko) { ... });
```

And that gave us a reduction of 80% of the requests and around the same number for the Javascript payload.

**Added AngularJS bonus**

This might not be of interest to you, but maybe for other readers. The reason we didn't get a 99% reduction of requests is because AngularJS uses something called 'directives'. These are like HTML templates. Those HTML templates still needed to be downloaded every time they were used.

They were also included in our `/app` folder - hence we had to add an IgnoreRoute in the routeconfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("app/");
```

I Googled, but couldn't find anything similair for Durandal. So Angular will go and get all of the small HTML files, but will first check its `$templatecache`. In case the HTML content is not in the cache, it goes out and downloads it and places it in the cache, so it needs to be downloaded only once.

We, well I, wrote a T4 generator that outputs a JS file in which all the HTML files in the /app folder are added to the `$templatecache`. So the output would look like:

```
angular.module('myapp').run(function($templateCache) {
  /// For all *.html files in the /app folder and its children
  $templateCache.put('...filename...', '...content of html file ...');
});
```

Because this .JS file was inside the /app folder, it would immediately get bundled with the application, no more configuration required. This got our requests down for the whole application to just 1. Since the amount of HTML was quite small, it seemed to be faster to do 1 larger request, then multiple smaller ones.

Point is: if Durandal has something similair and it will look for some templates, find the caching mechanism ( because it will have it ) and try to tap into that.

**Controlling bundling and minification**

I'll quote this site: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

> Bundling and minification is enabled or disabled by setting the value
>   of the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config
>   file. In the following XML, debug is set to true so bundling and
>   minification is disabled.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

So for your release build - this flag shouldn't be set and thus bundling + minification should happen.
But of course, you will want to test locally - you can either remove this from your web.config or override it with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

**Deployment to Azure**

Then you mention deployment to Azure. I don't know how this would be any different from deploying to a local server. We used web-deploy. Bundling and minification doesn't happen build-time, so there are no changes in the build process. Also, the optimization framework is being deployed with the site - so no difficult things for deployment either.

Maybe one thing though: you could consider adding the CDN for the libraries you are using:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
```

In case the CDN location of jQuery was already cached by the client's browser, you'll save another request.

Measuring the performance was easy: just open up the network tab on Chrome and reload the page ( make sure it's not caching ). Check the total number of requests and the total amount of data downloaded. Like I said: we saw a huge improvement.

Well, hope it helps or points you in a right direction.

Comment: Dude, I just looked at this again - so simple and well-explained.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The below answers are pretty complicated.  I've just gone through this with a simple(r) approach here:

https://lifelibertycode.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/how-to-bundle-up-your-mvc-durandal-app/

The steps below:

**Step 1: Install Node**

**Step 2: Install Gulp**

```
$ npm install --global gulp
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

**Step 3: Create your gulpfile.js**

This should be at the root of your project, and should initially contain this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

**Step 4: Install gulp-durandal**

```
npm install gulp-durandal --save-dev
```

**Step 5: Update your gulpfile.js**

```
var durandal = require('gulp-durandal');

gulp.task('durandal', function(){
    durandal({
            baseDir: 'app',   //same as default, so not really required.
            main: 'main.js',  //same as default, so not really required.
            output: 'main.js', //same as default, so not really required.
            almond: true,
            minify: true
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dir/to/save/the/output'));
});
```

**Step 6: Add a post-build event to your project**

```
if '$(Configuration)'=='Release' (
    cd $(ProjectDir)
    gulp durandal
)
```

**Step 7: Add a pre-build event to your project**

I needed this because occasionally gulp would hang when generating the new main-built.js on top of an existing version. So I just delete the old version before the build begins:

```
if '$(Configuration)'=='Release' (
    cd $(ProjectDir)/app
    del main-built.js
    del main-built.js.map
)
```

Now, when you build your project, you’ll generate a new main-built.js file each time that can be served down to your clients. Sweet.

At this point, you probably have some concerns.

**How do I keep my files un-bundled when I’m debugging?**

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/App/main"></script>
    } else {
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/main-built")
    }
```

Where ‘main-built’ is defined in your BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/main-built").Include(
    "~/app/main-built.js"));
```

**How do I bust cache when I have new stuff to ship?**

If you’re using the above approach, bundling will take care of this for you. ASP.NET will detect a change to your main-built.js file and append a unique identifier to your bundles to bust the cache.

**What if my client has downloaded my SPA, and then I ship an update. Won’t the (outdated) client-side code stick around until they refresh?**

Yup. Unless you leverage build versioning to tell the client when it’s out of date, and then tell the user.

Answer (score 0):

I happen have written a blog post about this:

https://javascriptkicks.com/articles/4230

Hopefully that helps you out

Comment: Excellent blog post!  I just flipped it into my Flipboard magazine.  Thank you for the contribution.