# Is there a way to minify and bundle up unnamed modules in requirejs?

Tags: optimization, requirejs, require, bundling-and-minification

I have below in configuration for require

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    waitSeconds: 0,
    // alias libraries paths
    paths: {
        'application-configuration': 'Scripts/App/application-configuration',
        'sessionService': 'Scripts/App/Services/ sessionServices',
        'ajaxService': 'Scripts/App/Services/ajaxServices',
        'alertsService': 'Scripts/App/Services/alertsServices',
```

The list is huge. These are unnamed modules. I need to minify and bundle-up in one single request.

The suggestion mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585774/bundling-and-minifying-modular-javascript-requirejs-amd-with-asp-net-mvc) says to strictly use the named modules.
Is there a way for unnamed modules/scenario like above?

Note: I understand its a good idea to name your modules, but the files are large in number I want to avoid naming all of them at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to have modules using an anonymous `define` call be used in the *input* of your bundling process. You don't have to open each and every file and add a module name in order to bundle them.

However, the bundler *will* have to turn all the anonymous calls into named calls. There's no way around it. This is automatic though, so it should not be a big deal.

> I understand its a good idea to name your modules.

You should let your bundler do the naming. Putting the names in yourself is a bad idea.

Comment: Louis, what name will you be providing in the bundle like, 
require.cofig({ 
   bundles: {
      'bundle/libs': [
         "<WhatName?>"
      ]
   }
})

Comment: If its same as the file name, tried and it didn't work.